# Issue parsing Content-Range header in angular app (returns null)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My .NET API server is returning some data to my Angular client and it sets the `Content-Range` header like so:

```
var response = await base.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
const string unit = "items";

response.Headers.Add("Accept-Ranges", unit);
response.Headers.Add("Range-Unit", unit);
response.Content.Headers.ContentRange = new ContentRangeHeaderValue(_requestedFrom, _requestedTo, _totalCount)
            {
                Unit = unit
            };
```

And this is seemingly working fine, as my network tab shows: `Content-Range:items 0-9/122`

The problem that I have is, when I attempt to parse this data, the parsing seemingly fails:

```
var response = parseRange(headers('Content-Range'));
console.log("response " + response);
```

The console logs: `responce null`. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Edit. `parseRange` function

```
function parseRange(hdr) {
  var m = hdr && hdr.match(/^(?:items )?(\d+)-(\d+)\/(\d+|\*)$/);
  if(m) {
    return {
      from: +m[1],
      to: +m[2],
      total: m[3] === '*' ? Infinity : +m[3]
    };
  } else if(hdr === '*/0') {
    return { total: 0 };
  }
  return null;
}
```

`hdr` in this function is null, so it appears the `headers()` function is the issue?

Comment: You need to provide the source for the `parseRange` and `headers` functions.

Comment: @TaylorBuchanan Those were there when I got here, I assumed they were native to angular/js... :( That's probably where the issue is. Searching for those functions returns nothing.

Comment: There is a `headers` function on the $http response object Angular provides, but I see no reference to that response here. There are no built-in range parsing capabilities.

Comment: @TaylorBuchanan found the `parseRange` function, added it in the edit. the `headers` looks like its from the http responce

Comment: The `parseRange` function works fine when passed the example header you provided. Please provide more code from the $http promise so we know if the `headers` function is being used correctly.

Comment: @TaylorBuchanan it's the first thing done in the success, the headers is included: `.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {` I did a dump of the responce headers and `content-range` did not show up at all in the log even though i can see it in the networking tab...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was actually on the server side, I needed to add content-range to the exposed headers:

```
 [EnableCors("http://localhost:3000", "*", "*", exposedHeaders: "Content-Range")]
```