# Why is Google Drive returning 'Failed to parse Content-Range header.'?

Tags: google-drive-api, dotnet-httpclient

Here's my simple-dimple code for resuming a (possibly) interrupted upload to Google Drive:

```
Using message = New ByteArrayContent(New Byte() {})
        message.Headers.ContentRange = New Headers.ContentRangeHeaderValue(Session.Size)
        'message.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Range", "bytes */*")
        Dim response = Await PutAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=" & Session.Code, message)
        Dim msg = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync
        'ERR: this is always 'Failed to parse Content-Range header.'
        Dim position = 0L
        If response.Headers.Contains("Range") Then
            Dim range = response.Headers.GetValues("Range")
            position = range.First.SplitPlus("-")(1)
        End If
```

but Google keeps on returning

> Failed to parse Content-Range header.

I checked the header manually, and it seems ok:

```
Content-Range: bytes */389587456
Content-Length: 0
```

What may the matter be?

What I tried:

Using `StringContent` instead of `ByteArrayContent`

Using `TryAddWithoutValidation` with `*/*`

Neither work

With appeciation,

**UPDATE**

I tried uploading a new file from scratch. Fresh upload. Here's the code:

```
If response.StatusCode = 308 Then
            Using fileStream = New ThrottledFileStream(Session.FilePath)
                fileStream.Position = position
                Using Content = New StreamContent(fileStream)
                    Content.Headers.ContentRange = New Headers.ContentRangeHeaderValue(position, Session.Size, Session.Size)
                    Using Timer = New Timer(Sub(o)
                                                Dim ps As Long
                                                If fileStream.CanRead Then ps = fileStream.Position
                                                Progress.Invoke(New CloudUploadState With {.Response = response, .Position = ps})
                                            End Sub, Nothing, 0, 20000)
                        Dim finishResponse = Await Put("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=" & Session.Code, Content)
                        Progress.Invoke(New CloudUploadState With {.Response = finishResponse})
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
```

But i get the exact same response:`Failed to parse Content-Range header.`

This is after the entire file was uploaded (based on the time it takes to return, and the position of the filesteam)

Whats wrong with my request?

Thanks

For completeness, here's the entire code basically. I'd appreciate any help or pointers:

```
    Public Async Function Upload(Session As DriveSession, Progress As Action(Of CloudUploadState)) As Task Implements ICloudStorage.Upload
    Await EnsureCredentials()
    If Session.Code Is Nothing Then
        Dim path = Session.FilePath
        If Debugger.IsAttached Then path = IO.Path.Combine("Test", path.Replace("\\", "\").Replace(":", ""))
        Dim currentFolderId = ""
        For Each nextFolderName In path.Split("\")
            Dim url = $"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files(name,id)&q=name='{nextFolderName}'"
            If currentFolderId <> "" Then url &= $" and '{currentFolderId}' in parents"
            If path.EndsWith("\" & nextFolderName) Then
                Dim metadata = New JObject From {{"name", IO.Path.GetFileName(path)}}
                metadata("parents") = New JArray From {currentFolderId}
                Using message = New StringContent(metadata.ToString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                    message.Headers.Add("X-Upload-Content-Type", GetExtMime(IO.Path.GetExtension(path).LeftCut(".")))
                    message.Headers.Add("X-Upload-Content-Length", Session.Size)
                    Dim response = Await Post($"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable", message)
                    Session.Code = response.Headers.Location.QueryParams("upload_id")
                    Using d = GetSystemContext(True)
                        Dim ds = d.Find(Of DriveSession)(Session.ID)
                        ds.Code = Session.Code
                        d.SaveChanges()
                    End Using
                End Using
                'End If
            Else
                url &= " and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
                Dim ret = Await GetString(url)
                Dim files = ParseResponse(ret)
                If files.Count > 1 Then DevError("identical names")
                If files.Any Then
                    currentFolderId = files.First.Id
                Else
                    Dim data = New JObject From {{"name", nextFolderName}, {"mimeType", "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"}}
                    If currentFolderId IsNot Nothing Then data.Add(New JProperty("parents", New JArray(currentFolderId)))
                    Using content = New StringContent(data.ToString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                        Using response = Await Post("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files", content)
                            Dim message = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync
                            currentFolderId = JObject.Parse(message).Value(Of String)("id")
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Using message = New ByteArrayContent(New Byte() {})
        message.Headers.ContentRange = New Headers.ContentRangeHeaderValue(Session.Size)
        Dim response = Await PutAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=" & Session.Code, message)
        Dim position = 0L
        If response.Headers.Contains("Range") Then
            Dim range = response.Headers.GetValues("Range")
            position = range.First.SplitPlus("-")(1)
        End If
        Progress.Invoke(New CloudUploadState With {.Response = response, .Position = position})
        If response.StatusCode = 308 Then
            Using fileStream = New ThrottledFileStream(Session.FilePath)
                fileStream.Position = position
                Using Content = New StreamContent(fileStream)
                    Content.Headers.ContentRange = New Headers.ContentRangeHeaderValue(position, Session.Size, Session.Size)
                    Using Timer = New Timer(Sub(o)
                                                Dim ps As Long
                                                If fileStream.CanRead Then ps = fileStream.Position
                                                Progress.Invoke(New CloudUploadState With {.Response = response, .Position = ps})
                                            End Sub, Nothing, 0, 30000)
                        Dim finishResponse = Await PutAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=" & Session.Code, Content)
                        Progress.Invoke(New CloudUploadState With {.Response = finishResponse})
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: I am not familiar with vb.net, but here is a sample code for a resumable upload to Google Drive: https://www.example-code.com/vbnet/google_drive_resumable_upload.asp Maybe those links are also helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37124205/google-drive-resumable-uploads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235259/issue-parsing-content-range-header-in-angular-app-returns-null https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1227

Comment: Hi. The first and last links are using external sdks, which I'm trying to avoid. The 2nd link shows an example using Post, which is against Google's directives, and doesn't work in any case. Any other ideas?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by external SDKs, https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1227 is on the official Google API GitHub and uses Google Drive API upload methods. https://www.example-code.com/vbnet/google_drive_resumable_upload.asp also uses Google methods to perform a POST request to Google Drive. Why is using POST requests against Google's directives?

Comment: Hi. Chilkat is defintely a 3rd party api. From `github`, I'm sorry, not 'external'. What I meant was, it's not using standard `REST` api. Here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resume-upload google writes to use a `PUT` for getting the range. quote: To request the upload status, create an empty PUT request to the resumable session URI. Any ideas for getting the range correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. got it. was missing in the request "content-Length:0"

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake, but I fixed it by changing to:

```
"Content-Range: bytes 0-*/*"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).