# Failed to parse Content-Range header when trying resumable uploads to google storage

Tags: python, flask, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a large file to google storage using chunking as outlined in their tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/performing-resumable-uploads#multiple-chunks). I am using Python(Flask) and their JSON REST api since my  use case cant work with the existing python packages that are not so well documented. The file chunks are coming from dropzone on the browser frontend.

Below is the code I have (Partial code)

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename=os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'],
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']) 

def start_resumable_upload_session(name, mime_type):
    """
    Name is the filename for the new object being uploaded 
    """
    url = f"https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/test-bucket-alpha-1/o?uploadType=resumable&name={name}"
    headers = {
        "X-Upload-Content-Type":mime_type
    }
    #        "X-Upload-Content-Length":"262144"
    #prep an authenticated session to make requests 
    authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)

    resp = authed_session.post(url, headers=headers)

    if resp.status_code == 200:
        return resp.headers.get('Location',None)
    else:
        return None 

authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials) 


sess_uri = start_resumable_upload_session(file_chunk.filename, file_chunk.content_type)
cn_length = len(file_chunk.read())
tot_size = int(request.form.get("dztotalfilesize"))
headers = {
            "Content-Length": str(cn_length),
            "Content-Range": f"bytes 0-{str(cn_length-1)}/{str(tot_size-1)}"
        }
resp = authed_session.put(sess_uri,data=file_chunk.read(), headers=headers)
```

The response text is `Failed to parse Content-Range header` or even when I tried adjusting inputs to debug, no response is produced and the request just times out.

What may I be doing wrong in my logic? I also appreciate links to code snippets that may shed light.

**UPDATE - RESOLVED**
As pointed out in the comment below, the correct header should be:

```
headers = {
        "Content-Length": str(cn_length),
        "Content-Range": f"bytes 0-{str(cn_length-1)}/{str(tot_size)}"
    }
```

i.e if an object is 1000 bytes, your ranges will go from 0-999 but overall size should still be 1000.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but `tot_size-1` looks like a mistake. For a zero byte object, the size would be -1, which would be an invalid header. Can you print the resulting content-range header to make sure it makes sense?

Comment: Yes @BrandonYarbrough, that turned out to be the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a [sample application](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-file-transfer-json-python/blob/master/chunked_transfer.py#L123) which includes a `Resumable Uploads` in Python, using the [`google-api-python-client`](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/)

You might be interested in this line:

```
media = MediaFileUpload(filename, chunksize=CHUNKSIZE, resumable=True)
if not media.mimetype():
    media = MediaFileUpload(filename, DEFAULT_MIMETYPE, resumable=True)
request = service.objects().insert(bucket=bucket_name, name=object_name,
                                 media_body=media)
```

Additionally, [this](https://dev.to/sethmlarson/python-data-streaming-to-google-cloud-storage-with-resumable-uploads-458h) is another example:

```
# Create a Resumable Upload
url = (
    f'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/'
    f'{bucket.name}/o?uploadType=resumable'
)
upload = ResumableUpload(
    upload_url=url,
    chunk_size=chunk_size
)
transport = AuthorizedSession(credentials=client._credentials)

# Start using the Resumable Upload
upload.initiate(
    transport=transport,
    content_type='application/octet-stream',
    stream=stream,
    metadata={'name': blob.name}
)
```

Finally, this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59478445/why-is-google-drive-returning-failed-to-parse-content-range-header) was solved by setting right the `Content-Length`.